# Can´t do a tweet with twitter app - android

Tags: android, twitter, share

i have a problem with my app, i tried this code to do a tweet from my app without using the sdk:

```
 ImageView Twitter = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
 Twitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View view) {
             Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
             sharingIntent.setType("plain/text");
             sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                     "This is the text that will be shared.");
             startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,
                     "Share via"));
     }

 });
```

I just wanted to share text+link, but when i press the button, TWITTER  DOESNT EXISTS, facebook too don't appear!
Else this two apps, appear: gmail, bluetooth, edmodo, etc..
So, i tried to do it for other way, "beast way" :D

```
 ImageView Twitter = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    Twitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent browserIntent = 
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                    Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lol.king%20-%20This%20app%20is%20amazing,%20i%20love%20it!"));
           startActivity(browserIntent);




            }});
```

If you read carefully the link and try it (in ur computer) you will see the good results, BUT when i do it in my android phone, it give me the chance to run this link with Twitter App(if you dont have it, will go directly to the link and there will be no problem). And of course when i click it, appear an error: "Twitter has stopped"). Can you help me to tweet Links+texts (or if is impossible to share both, just Link?

Comment: You phone have twitter app?.. Post your logcat what happen.

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur yes, my phone have twitter app. Mhmm.. can't put the logcat, cause in the AMD phone there is no twitter app :/
If u want i post the logcat of that, but could be different i think

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur i tried to click this button on the AMD and it just open the navigator, IN MY PHONE, it gives me the change to choose between navigator or twitter, and if i click twitter, it says: "twitter has stopped".